# SSL Certificate Certbot failed to download the challenge files

Tags: node.js, ssl

Im working on getting SSL certificate for my site. Im working on an aws ubunutu EC2 instance. My app is run by a node server, i previously setup a dummy certificate through openssl to test. Now i want a validate one. When i run `sudo certbot certonly --standalone -d <MY_DOMAIN>` i get the following.

`The Certificate Authority failed to download the challenge files from the temporary standalone webserver started by Certbot on port 80. Ensure that the listed domains point to this machine and that it can accept inbound connections from the internet.`

some additional errors:
`Certbot failed to authenticate some domains (authenticator: standalone)`
`Invalid response from <MY_DOMAIN>.well-known/acme-challenge/CPtnSoDf7dx00D9RmvaTHA50gN9gIengnG-XImGI2Nc: "<!doctype html><html lang=\"en\"><head><meta charset=\"utf-8\"/><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width,initial-scale=1\"/>"`

Comment: Additional context, my ec2 security group has open connections on port 80 and 443 from anywhere. Dont believe thats my issue